# Связь между классами

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++-cli

Есть:
Список работ выполняемых сотрудником. Список содержит Ф.И.О. исполнителя, название проекта и т.д.

Не совсем понимаю, какие классы должны быть, и как организовать их взаимодействие.
Класс Member  с полями (Ф.И.О., название проекта) и внутри еще одно поле-класс TaskList?

Comment: Какую задачу должны решать взаимодействующие классы?

Comment: Непонятно что нужно делать-то. Есть список/массив сотрудников (обьекты классов с полями ФИО и полем с типом работы). А что делать с сотрудниками? Работы можешь в enum прописать и присваивать полям работы значения из enum, чтобы более ООПэшно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что нужны класс сотрудника, класс работы. А потом, как в базе данных - класс записей, в которых есть указатель на сотрудника и на выполняемую работу.

Если нужно быстро искать - можно прямо в класс сотрудника внести список классов работ.